# Need to hide column data when it is folder or display data when it is file on SharePoint document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, column

We are using "Column Formatting" option on SP document library for particular column. When it folder, then that option need to hide, if it file or document inside the folder, then option need to visible. Below json code i am trying but its is hiding option for both file and folder. Can anyone suggest us with correct code line.

[image: Screenshot]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"\"}"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDarker--hover"
  },
  "style": {
    "border": "none",
    "cursor": "pointer",
    "background-color": "#D5D5D5",
    "color": "#000",
    "padding": "4px 4px 4px 10px",
    "border-radius": "5px",
    "display": "=if([$ItemType]=='Folder', 'none', 'inherit')"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "Request approval"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Instead of `[$ItemType]` use `[$ContentType]`. Also, make sure you have shown/included content type column in the library view. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FSObjType` field to decide whether it's folder or document. If it's value is 0 then it's document and it it's value is 1 then it's folder. See official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee537053(v=office.15))

You can use following JSON which should give correct output which you want:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "{\"id\":\"{flowID}\"}"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDarker--hover"
  },
  "style": {
    "border": "none",
    "cursor": "pointer",
    "background-color": "#D5D5D5",
    "color": "#000",
    "padding": "4px 4px 4px 10px",
    "border-radius": "5px",
    "display": "=if(  ([$FSObjType] == '0' ), 'block', 'none')"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "Request Approval"
    }
  ]
}
```

See output below:

[image]

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?

Comment: @RaytheonXie-MSFT I am not sure to whom you are asking? are you asking me or to author of this question?